# Flow type: handling a function argument that could be many types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm not sure how to get flow to handle arguments that are a union of many types.

Example Code:

```
// @flow

function foo(a: string | number[] | Date): string {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        return a.toUpperCase()
    } else if (a instanceof Array) {
        return a.join('-')
    } else if (a instanceof Date) {
        return a.getMonth().toString() 
    }
    return ''
}
```

Flow errors:

```
6:  } else if (a instanceof Array) {
                            ^ Array. This type is incompatible with
3: function foo(a: string | number[] | Date): string {
                   ^ union: string | array type | Date
```

[Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqJLLABQCGAXKAM7YBOu6A5qAD6jqoC2ARgKb0A2gF12oACLls-AJTU6jFqADeiAJC5IoUtgCeAB36xt5UAF5LoAOSKmza7NWJQr0Ovr9sqeoXIA6bFgAVQMjegBhchp+UlkNAF9QfmgY0C0dMyY6cixjbQBBenpyPSc1V3UPLx8-fwArWCZSawBaRxc3JJS0jIp09By8k0lpOWc3Ss9vX1AA5i8AWQJsAAs4wNgAZQZ7ONBO1wTO6pnCa2tEBKA)

Flow does seem to notice when I use `typeof` but that isn't always good enough since `typeof []` and `typeof new Date()` are both `"object"`.

How do I make flow give me a green check here?

Comment: Does seem like a bug, but FYI it works fine with `Array.isArray`, which you essentially always want to use instead of `instanceof Array`.

Comment: You don't seem particularly confident in the type safety of `foo`, since you define the default case`return ''`.

Comment: @ftor flow doesn't seem to realize those are all three of the options either, so without that gauranteed `return ''` you get `string: This type is incompatible with an implicitly-returned undefined.`

Comment: This is interesting. In Haskell the compiler can infer all cases, i.e. you don't necessarily need a default case.

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented with your example and changing order of `if`s helped!

```
// @flow

function foo(a: string | number[] | Date): string {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        return a.toUpperCase()
    } else if (a instanceof Date) {
        return a.getMonth().toString()
    } else if (a instanceof Array) {
        return a.join('-')
    }
    return ''
}
```

gives no error.

Don't ask me why :)

Comment: You should log a bug.